# Why are typical UART baud rates not in multiples of 1000?

Tags: electrical-engineering, embedded-systems

Why are typical baud rates not in multiples of 1000 instead of being in multiples of 300 i.e. 4800, 9600, 19200, 115200, etc...? Is there a mathematical or electrical reason behind this?

Answer (score 11):

This goes way, way back to the [Bell 103 modem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_103_modem) from 1962.  It operated at 300 bits per second for reasons deriving from the use of [audio frequency-shift keying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency-shift_keying) to modulate data; the frequencies available were limited by the quality of the phone lines.  All common serial data rates since then are integer multiples of this rate.